# How to refresh a listview populated with search result activity

Tags: android, listview

I use SimpleCursorAdapter to populate DB search results into a ListView.

The user may choose to delete an item from the list using long click.

I've used

```
((BaseAdapter) mListView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and

```
mListView.invalidateViews();
```

to get the ListView refreshed after deleting the Item from the DB in the `onItemLongClick` listener.

I seem to be lost in the flow probably due to the search service activation. My search activity is Single Top but my `handleItnet()` is called only once (from `onCreate()`)

Comment: A code spinet will help us a lot to solve your problem.

Comment: You need to delete the item from your Adapter (not from some kind of DB), and then call notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: Better to use Loader for it. Please refer [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html)